# Error import pandas as pd en pycharm

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pycharm

Estoy intentando importar pandas: `import pandas as pd`, pero me da el siguiente error:

```
 import pandas as pd   File "C:\Users\Jesús\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\pandas\__init__.py", line 11, in <module>
    __import__(dependency)   File "C:\Users\Jesús\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 145, in <module>
    from . import lib ValueError: source code string cannot contain null bytes
```

Estoy usando la última versión de **Python 3.8.1** y tengo descargada la librería en **pycharm**

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que parece es un error del fichero, probablemente por estar en UTF-16 en vez de UTF-8. En varios problemas iguales al tuyo, lo que se suele hacer es editar manualmente el fichero para quitar estos caracteres.

Revisa [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31233777/python-source-code-string-cannot-contain-null-bytes), o [guarda el fichero como UTF-8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12988619/python-cturtle-module-not-loading). Tambien puedes intentar remover todos los [null characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2398393/identifying-and-removing-null-characters-in-unix/2399817#2399817) del fichero automaticamente.

```
tr < file-with-nulls -d '\000' > file-without-nulls
```

Answer (score 0):

Es posible que no tengas bien instalado pandas, tenes que revisar que para python3 tenga todas las dependencias (Muchas veces por confusión las solemos instalar para python2).

Esta es la lista de las dependencias.
[Lista](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/install.html#dependencies)

Podes probar con:

```
pip3 install numpy pandas
```

Como veo que es lo estas haciendo en windows, no te olvides de ejecutar el CMD como administrador.